# Holding off on create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to have a form that anyone can fill out, but must be logged in to submit it - if not, put the process on hold until they do.

My thought process is if someone comes across the form, it checks if they are logged in, if not the user can still fill it out, but instead prompted to log in or sign up as opposed to "Submit". If they click on either link (log in/sign up) I want it to save the form data, most likely to the session, have them log in/sign up, and then have the computer check to see if there is a saved form, and if so display a confirmation like screen, where the newly registered user can accept it.

I've posted come code below that I thought would work, but it isn't - and I was thinking that knowing rails, theres probably some convention out the to do this much faster and easier!

And I don't believe the way that I am passing the form data around is correct, so if anyone can correct me there that would be great!

View

```
<%= form_for :comment, :url => {:action => 'create'} %>
    form fields here
<% if current_user %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Log In", save_to_session_and_log_in_path(:comment => :comment) %> or 
    <%= link_to "Sign Up", save_to_session_and_sign_up_path(:comment => :comment) %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def save_to_session_and_log_in_path
  session[:temp_comment] = Comment.new(params[:comment])
  redirect_to log_in_path
end

def save_to_session_and_sign_up_path
  session[:temp_comment] = Comment.new(params[:comment])
  redirect_to sign_up_path
end
```

User* Controller

```
def create 
  #Normal create action, under the redirect:
  if session[:temp_comment]
    redirect_to confirm_comment
  else
    redirect_to users_home_page
  end
end
```

---

The error I am receiving is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#show

Couldn't find Comment with id=save_to_session_and_log_in
Rails.root: scrubbed

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:87:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"comment"=>"comment"
"id"=>"save_to_session_and_log_in"}
```

I've tried tweaking it every which way but it still keeps getting me here so I am unable to test if any of my code is working

Comment: Wouldn't it be just `session[:temp_comment] = params[:comment]`? Does the comment show up in the URL params correctly?

Comment: @mind.blank I updated the post, I can't tell which of our solutions would work because I can't get past the error above

Comment: Seems like you cant save ActiveRecord model in session. Instead you can save params[:comment]

Comment: @laise even if I replace Comment.new(params[:comment]) with just params[:comment] I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

What are your CommentsController#create and #show action? About your error, could you paste the rake routes result for the `save_to_session_and_log_in_path` and the `save_to_session_and_sign_up_path` methods? Since you don't have an `id` at that moment, you should set them as `collection` routes.

--

The way I'd do it, though, is submitting the form to different controllers that will handle each scenario. That way, your `CommentsController` will be for logged in users and you can have a `TemporaryCommentsController` that will take care of comments made by guests.

--

Also, depending on the comment's field, I don't know if it's a great idea to store them in the session. You could probably store a tmp_comment_id in the session and recover that from the DB. Also, delete all records with a cron-job.  (This is a problem only when "the comment is big and 'hard' to serialize" though).